# React useEffect: is it possible to set dependencies with a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm calling a function to determine if a set of form fields are valid. I have a set of state variables that should trigger `useEffect()` but apparently I can't make an array beforehand like this without getting a warning:

```
const states = [name, email, password]

useEffect(() => {
  someFunction({ states })
}, states)
```

Instead I have to do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  someFunction({ states: [name, email, password] })
}, [name, email, password])
```

This is annoying because I plan on using this pattern on other forms that will have 10-20 fields, so I hate to clutter it up by building that whole array every time. Is there a better way?

Comment: This should be possible though. What problem do you encounter specifically? Show it.

Comment: you can use the spread operator `[...states]`, imo there are cases where you want to listen to array change

Comment: The spread operator gives me the same eslint warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes, it's possible. What you're seeing is a warning from eslint, and you can disable it in a line/file basis. Check the docs here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules

```js
const states = [name, email, password]

useEffect(() => {
  someFunction({ states })
}, states) // eslint-disable-line <eslint-error-id>
```

It's rarely a good idea to have a variable like that, as eslint won't be able to tell you if you're missing a dependency.

Comment: That makes sense for eslint. Not great for making it DRY, as I also would use this same array in the submit function, but I understand.

Comment: @Glenn You're free to disable that rule if you want. Think about what it gives to you, and if it matches your code style. It's up to you after all. In my opinion, it's just a minor problem (sometimes, it's not common to share all of the dependencies). But it may detect important hard-to-find bugs for you

Comment: ultimately I decided to disable the warning and use a variable due to needing multiple lengthy lists, but I am defining the array just above the useEffect() call, so it is easy to see what's going in there. Good compromise I think.

Comment: P.S. I actually think this linting rule is not well thought out. There are many cases where I am setting one state var with the spread operator because another state var changed. The linting rule often thinks I need to include both in the dependency list, which of course leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: I think the mindset around the rule is _having every useEffect doing atomic/minimal things_. Remember that the `set` in useState accepts the object, but also cana ccept a function that receves the old state as the first parameter, so you wouldn't need to add the old state to the useEffect. _In my experience_, I've never had a case where that rule didn't apply. Maybe, try to simplify your useEffect. It should be simple and as atomic as possible

Comment: I am indeed doing something really simple. I am checking every field to see if they all are valid (each one has a `valid` property). If they are all valid, I am just setting one state variable to enable a submit button. When there are 10+ fields, there is no getting around passing them all in. This strikes me as a pretty common use case.

Comment: If it's a form-like component, I would consider having the form data in a object as a prop, instead of every field as a prop. But well, it depends